# Validate Form Element in one function in jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, function, element, validating

```
var client_name     = $("#client_name");
var client_surname  = $("#client_surname");
var client_phone    = $("#client_phone");
var form            = $("#billing_form");

Validate(client_name);
Validate(client_surname);
Validate(client_phone);

form.submit(function(e){
  if(Validate(client_name) && Validate(client_surname) && Validate(client_phone)){
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log("True");
     return true;
 } else {
     console.log("False");
     return false;  
 }
});

function Validate(id){
 id.blur(function(){
  if(id.val().length <= 0){
     id.addClass("input_error").removeClass("input_apply").css("border","1px solid #ff0000");
     return false;
} else {
     id.removeClass("input_error").removeAttr("style");
     return true;
       }
   });
}
```

I wrote this function for validating all of my inputs in one function but it does not return true **any time**.İf I fill all of the inputs it returns false again. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Validate` function doesn't return anything. That's pretty evident from the fact that there's no `return` statement inside that function. All it does is bind a `blur` event handler on the element that's passed to it; the handler function for that event returns `true` or `false`, but that has absolutely no bearing on the `Validate` function.

I would suspect a lack of `return` inside a function implicitly results in `undefined` being returned, which in turn evaluates to `false` for boolean conditions, which is why you're never seeing `true` (because it never is). Just take out the event handler binding in your `Validate` function:

```
function Validate(id) {
    if (id.val().length <= 0) {
        id.addClass("input_error").removeClass("input_apply").css("border", "1px solid #ff0000");
        return false;
    } else {
        id.removeClass("input_error").removeAttr("style");
        return true;
    }
}
```

It won't do the validation as you're modifying the inputs values, but it should correctly validate them when you submit the form.

If you want to keep the `blur` event handler, then you could do it this way:

```
var client_name     = $("#client_name");
var client_surname  = $("#client_surname");
var client_phone    = $("#client_phone");
var form            = $("#billing_form");

function blurValidation() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if(this.value.length <= 0) {
        $this.addClass("input_error").removeClass("input_apply").css("border","1px solid #ff0000");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $this.removeClass("input_error").removeAttr("style");
        return true;
    }
}

client_name.blur(blurValidation);
client_surname.blur(blurValidation);
client_phone.blur(blurValidation);


form.submit(function(e){
    client_name.blur();
    client_surname.blur();
    client_phone.blur();
    if(Validate(client_name) && Validate(client_surname) && Validate(client_phone)){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("True");
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("False");
        return false;  
    }
});

function Validate(id){
    return !id.hasClass("input_error");
}
```

Comment: How will I catch the "blur" function of an element if I write it so?

Comment: @Onur If you're that attached to the `blur` event handler, set that up separately (not inside the `Validate` method) and simply check for the presence of the `input_error` class inside the `Validate` method instead (it fails if that class is present).

Comment: this worked but it has a bug. If I don't fill anything it returns True because of any element has class input_error :((

Comment: @Onur Edited to programmatically trigger the `blur` event on the three inputs when the form is submitted, so it will pick up the cases where some of them haven't been interacted with at all.

Comment: thank you Anthony I want to ask you something another. I have an email input. How will I test the email if it is real or not with these codes?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this `$("#client_name")` use `$("#client_name").val();`

**Replace**

```
if (id.val().length <= 0) {
```

**With**

```
if (id.val() == "") {
```

Comment: but I say in the function id.val() already. Does this have any differences Devang?

Comment: ohh i didnt see that . ok no prob but now check my edited answer.